# Segmentation fault, multiplying matrices using MPI library

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, mpi

I am writing a program that multiplies two matrices A and B which are stored in text files, and which size could be variant, so my program has to identify the size of matrix A and B, determine if they can be multiplied etc.

Well that's not the problem the real trouble is when I pass the data from master process to slave process, in my program I pass rows from master to slaves and the number of rows depends on the number of the rows of the matrix and the number of processes.

The matrix A is stored by rows, but the matrixB is stored by columns.

> matrixA[ 0 ] ----------------
>
> matrixA[ 1 ] ----------------
>
> matrixA[ 2 ] ----------------
>
> matrixB[ 0 ]     matrixB[ 1 ]     matrixB[ 2 ]     .........
>
> ```
> |           |         |     |
> |           |         |     |
> |           |         |     |
> ```

You can find the text files here (for input): [matrixA](https://www.dropbox.com/s/io2y8r7p0eb3pxr/matrixA.txt)     [matrixB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sqw445d89l4zi20/matrixB.txt).

After several days of 80's style debugging (means not debugger at all), I think the problem (the segmentation fault I get as output) is in these code-lines ( from the slave function):

```
void slave( int id, int slaves, double **matrixA, double **matrixB, double **matrixC )
{
    int type, columnsA, columnsB, rowsA, rowsB, Btype, offset, rows, averageRows, extraRows;
    MPI_Status status;

    /* Recieves columns of A and B from master. */
    type = 3;

    MPI_Recv( &columnsA, 1, MPI_INT, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
    MPI_Recv( &rowsA, 1, MPI_INT, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
    MPI_Recv( &columnsB, 1, MPI_INT, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
    MPI_Recv( &rowsB, 1, MPI_INT, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
    printf( "%d slave recieved ColumnA = %d, RowsA = %d, ColumnB = %d, RowsB = %d.\n", id, columnsA, rowsA, columnsB, rowsB );


    /* Recieve from master. */
    type = 0;

    MPI_Recv( &offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
    MPI_Recv( &rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );

    matrixAllocate( &matrixA, columnsA, rows );
    matrixAllocate( &matrixB, rowsB, columnsB );
    matrixAllocate( &matrixC, columnsB, rows );
    printf( "Correctly allocated.\n" );

    /* This part is only to see if the mem was correctly allocated.*/
    for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < columnsA; j++)
            matrixA[ i ][ j ] = i + j;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < columnsB; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < rowsB; j++)
            matrixB[ i ][ j ] = i * j;
    }

    if ( id == 1 ){
        matrixPrinter( "matrixA", matrixA, rows, columnsA );
        matrixBPrinter( "matrixB", matrixB, rowsB, columnsB );
        matrixPrinter( "matrixC", matrixC, rows, columnsB );
    }

    MPI_Recv( &matrixA, ( rows * columnsA ) , MPI_DOUBLE, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
    MPI_Recv( &matrixB, ( rowsB * columnsB ), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
    printf( "Correctly recieved.\n" );

    matrixPrinter( "matrixA", matrixA, rows, columnsA );
    matrixBPrinter( "matrixB", matrixB, rowsB, columnsB );
    matrixPrinter( "matrixC", matrixC, rows, columnsB );

    if ( id == 1 ){
        printf( "My id is %d.\n", id );
        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ){
            for( int j = 0; j < columnsA; j++ ){
                printf( "%lf    ", matrixA[ i ][ j ] );
            }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

**The whole code can be found here**. [MPI matrix multiplier in C.](http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/83799792)

**The output of the terminal is:**

[image]

Comment: It seems rather unfriendly to include the (input) text as images. What if someone actually wanted to look at what this does?

Comment: I added the text files used for input.

Comment: When I encounter segfaults, I run the program using gdb. When the segfault occur, I type bt, which prints the stack trace, now it's very easy to spot the problem.

Comment: @Mellowcandle I tried doing that, but mpi is kinda hard to "just" gdb or valgrind :) Did you? Start with `sudo -E mpirun -np 2 xterm -e "gdb test multiply A B C"`, or use Bullet 6 in [these debugging FAQ](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is, the matrix is of type "double **" as allocated in "matrixAllocate". When sending and receiving data, MPI assumes that the buf contains the data continiously as an 1-d array, which, however, is not the case.(you can easily check that by printing out the address of each matrix entry)

I think it's a famous pitfall in C: pointer and array are different. If the matrix is a 2-d array, then all the entries are laid out continuously.

My suggestion is to allocate the matrix as 1-d and do not use multidim subscript.

Comment: Good spot. +1 for the effort!

Comment: I tried passing rows by rows using a for loops, but still not working :(

Comment: matrix is changed into 1-d; return value of lineCounter is also changed because there's a also newline before EOF [modified code](http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/10470819)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto no passing by rows is not the problem, what taikou suggested is considered best practice, this is what scalapack does and what many other libraries do. They store N-dimensional matrices in a 1-D array, and keep a descriptor file for each matrix detailing the information about the N-dimensional array so you know what row or column you are in. Not only are things easier to use, its more efficient as well

Answer (score 1):

Without digging through all of your `MPI` code, I hate to post an answer like this but I would suggest using the compiler command `-Wall` in the future. It may help and pick up an error like this. For MPI and anything computational related you almost always need the `-Wall` compiler command

look at the output and list of warnings from your code.

```
$ mpic++ test.cpp -Wall -o  test
test.cpp:30:63: warning: unused variable 'rank' [-Wunused-variable]
    int lineA, lineB, columnA, columnB, id, size, rc, slaves, rank, source;
                                                              ^
test.cpp:30:69: warning: unused variable 'source' [-Wunused-variable]
    int lineA, lineB, columnA, columnB, id, size, rc, slaves, rank, source;
                                                                    ^
test.cpp:126:50: warning: variable 'matrixC' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
            slave( id, slaves, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC );
                                                 ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:34:21: note: initialize the variable 'matrixC' to silence this warning
           **matrixC;
                    ^
                     = NULL
test.cpp:126:41: warning: variable 'matrixB' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
            slave( id, slaves, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC );
                                        ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:33:21: note: initialize the variable 'matrixB' to silence this warning
           **matrixB,
                    ^
                     = NULL
test.cpp:85:44: warning: variable 'rc' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
                MPI_Abort( MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc );
                                           ^~
test.cpp:30:53: note: initialize the variable 'rc' to silence this warning
    int lineA, lineB, columnA, columnB, id, size, rc, slaves, rank, source;
                                                    ^
                                                     = 0
test.cpp:126:32: warning: variable 'matrixA' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
            slave( id, slaves, matrixA, matrixB, matrixC );
                               ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:32:21: note: initialize the variable 'matrixA' to silence this warning
    double **matrixA,
                    ^
                     = NULL
test.cpp:398:20: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    matrixPrinter( "matrixA", matrixA, rows, columnsA );
                   ^
test.cpp:399:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    matrixBPrinter( "matrixB", matrixB, rowsB, columnsB );
                    ^
test.cpp:400:20: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    matrixPrinter( "matrixC", matrixC, rows, columnsB );
                   ^
test.cpp:407:20: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    matrixPrinter( "matrixA", matrixA, rows, columnsA );
                   ^
test.cpp:408:21: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    matrixBPrinter( "matrixB", matrixB, rowsB, columnsB );
                    ^
test.cpp:409:20: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    matrixPrinter( "matrixC", matrixC, rows, columnsB );
                   ^
test.cpp:363:70: warning: unused variable 'averageRows' [-Wunused-variable]
    int type, columnsA, columnsB, rowsA, rowsB, Btype, offset, rows, averageRows, extraRows;
                                                                     ^
test.cpp:363:83: warning: unused variable 'extraRows' [-Wunused-variable]
    int type, columnsA, columnsB, rowsA, rowsB, Btype, offset, rows, averageRows, extraRows;
                                                                                  ^
test.cpp:363:49: warning: unused variable 'Btype' [-Wunused-variable]
    int type, columnsA, columnsB, rowsA, rowsB, Btype, offset, rows, averageRows, extraRows;
                                                ^
15 warnings generated.
```